# Why am I getting the error message ImportError: No module named <app>.urls?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-urls

I was recently building a django project. I have been looking through the files for a couple of hours now and can't find the problem that would result in this kind of error message. Below, I will show you all of the relevant files within the project.

base `url.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^display/', include('diplay.urls')),

]
```

app `url.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

app `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>HEY!</h2>")
```

I'm not sure why this is not working because I found a similar format online, and it seemed that every line was similar to the other one. When I try running the server, it gives me the error statement

```
ImportError: No module named diplay.urls
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1, make sure your app name is `diplay` which is same as in your base `urls.py`, I think maybe there is typo, should change to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^display/', include('display.urls')),

]
```

2, make sure the file name of `urls` should be `urls.py` instead of `url.py` in both base and app folder

Answer (score 0):

Does app diplay exists or is it typo of display

```
> diplay.urls
```

Also does urls file in app exists